# What does "is hashed" mean when using the type command?

Tags: bash, command, shell-builtin

I was reading [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then) and trying out all of the commands in the first answer... I don't really have anything else better to do right now.

Anyways, I ran through them all in regards to `rm`. What piqued my interest is this:

```
root@headdesk:~# type ls
ls is /bin/ls
root@headdesk:~# hash ls
root@headdesk:~# type ls
ls is hashed (/bin/ls)
root@headdesk:~#
```

Running `help/man hash` is not very helpful, and `help type` isn't really either (it does not mention `hash` anywhere). Since I can't seem to find a relation in the man/info/help pages unless I am missing something, could someone please explain what `hash`ing is doing in regards to the `type` command?

Comment: your shell *remembers* where it finds a command. a `$PATH` search is brute forced otherwise, but if it finds a command it stores its location in a hash table *(supposed to be, anyway)* so it can call it up next time. if you do `PATH=$PATH` or `hash -r` it will forget all executables in the hash table. it doesnt *usually* affect anything, but it can make a difference for weird lookup tables compiled out of a list of empty files in the current directory, for instance. it used to make things a lot faster, but i dunno if its so true anymore. maybe if `$PATH` is huge,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash: just type `help hash` and you will get a help about the built-in command `hash`.

> Determine and remember the full pathname of each command NAME.

What that means is that after finding the location of a command the first time (or when hash is invoked), its location is remembered (hashed).

Comment: Makes sense - little bit of a different question, but it says obsolete at the  bottom of the `help` page for `type`. Are there any other commands that you can view if a command is hashed besides `type`?

Comment: @ekaj If you do `hash cat` to get cat hashed, `hash -t cat` will print the hashed directory. If `cat` is not hashed `hash -d cat`, the command `hash -t cat` will print `not found`.  The `Obsolete` part apply to the command `typeset` which happens to also be printed at the end of `type` in older bash help versions. Does not apply to `type`.

Answer (score 5):

It means stored in a hash table for quicker reference next time around.